# Why does Javascript (ES.next) force me to declare a function as async if I want to use await?

Tags: javascript, async-await, language-design

It seems like a compiler / parser should be smart enough to detect if a function uses `await` then it automatically becomes an `async` function.

Why am I forced to type the `async` keyword?  It adds clutter and there are many times where I forget to add it and I get an error and then I have to go and add it.

Would there be any disadvantage to having the compiler automatically promote the function to `async` when it sees `await` and just save everyone the hassle of dealing with it?

Comment: The fact that you sometimes forget to add it should be reason enough. If you're *writing* the code and forget to add it, what hope of figuring out what's going on would anyone else ever have?

Comment: Thanks.  I added ES7 in the title to be more specific.  While not a requirement of Javascript itself, I think pretty much every major Javascript implementation compiles to native code eventually.  At least for the section that are hot.

Comment: Without explicitly defining an function async, how the heck a reader can find out it is async? You don't expect a reader to read all of the body of the function to find an "await" to make sure it's async or not.

Comment: ES7 is already finalized. `async/await` is not part of ES7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare async functions to ES6 generator functions and it is pretty obvious:

```
function* x() {} // Generator function without 'yield'
Object.getPrototypeOf(x); // returns GeneratorFunction
```

Generator functions are inherently different from traditional functions, but they do not need to have a `yield` expression in their body. There was actually [a bug in the ES6 proposal](http://bugs.ecmascript.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1283) which stated that it is a syntax error if the generator function does not contain a `yield`, but it was quickly fixed:

> One important use case is prototyping with a dummy generator. Or the
>   case where you comment out a yield for debugging. That shouldn't
>   render the program illegal.

The same holds for async functions: According to [the draft](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-decls-exprs-static-semantics-early-errors), an async function is not required to have an `awaits` in its body while still behaving different from a traditional function.

Let's say you comment an `await` out. Should the interpreter then parse your async function as a traditional function and possibly break your whole code? Better not.